# WPF Converter : return a DrawingBrush created created in another file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have 2 designs for the checkbox control and I want to use one or the other depending on a boolean property from my ViewModel.

For that, I bind the Fill property of my checkbox and I create a converter:

```
<CheckBox Name="MyCheckBox" Style="{StaticResource CheckboxFilterStyle}" Fill="{Binding IsNice, Converter={StaticResosurce BoolToCheckboxFillColorConverter}}" />
```

Here is the 2 DrawingBrush defined in a separate xaml file

```
<DrawingBrush x:Key="FilterIconBlack" Stretch="Uniform">
        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            <DrawingGroup>
                <DrawingGroup.Children>
                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF000000" Geometry="F1 M 7.62485,10.6472L 12.8708,1.56098L 2.37891,1.56098L 7.62485,10.6472 Z ">
                        <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                            <Pen LineJoin="Round" Brush="#FF000000"/>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF000000" Geometry="F1 M 6.55899,7.70289L 8.69071,7.70289L 8.69071,14.0625L 6.55899,14.0625L 6.55899,7.70289 Z ">
                        <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                            <Pen LineJoin="Round" Brush="#FF000000"/>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                </DrawingGroup.Children>
            </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
    </DrawingBrush>

    <DrawingBrush x:Key="FilterIconOrange" Stretch="Uniform">
        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            <DrawingGroup>
                <DrawingGroup.Children>
                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="Orange" Geometry="F1 M 7.62485,10.6472L 12.8708,1.56098L 2.37891,1.56098L 7.62485,10.6472 Z ">
                        <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                            <Pen LineJoin="Round" Brush="Orange"/>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="Orange" Geometry="F1 M 6.55899,7.70289L 8.69071,7.70289L 8.69071,14.0625L 6.55899,14.0625L 6.55899,7.70289 Z ">
                        <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                            <Pen LineJoin="Round" Brush="Orange"/>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                </DrawingGroup.Children>
            </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
    </DrawingBrush>
```

My question is, how do I return one or the other in my converter? How do I create a DrawingBrush from a DrawingBrush defined in another .xaml file?

Comment: Move those to your `app.xaml` and use `return (bool)value ? (DrawingRBrush)Application.Current.FindResource("FilterIconOrange") : (DrawingRBrush)Application.Current.FindResource("FilterIconBlack");` in your converter

Comment: Don't put everything in app.xaml. Move your shared resources to a resource dictionary and merge them in app.xaml. You could use a datatrigger rather than a converter. Looks to me like you could also merge the two geometries into one and simplify that markup. Maybe use a drawingvisual and path.

Comment: Actually, I used a DataTrigger to achieve what I wanted, but I wanted to know whether it is possible to reference a resource from a file. Both answers helped me, thanks